# autodesk forge: How to download bubble in zip format from using java sdk

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am using java SDK from autodesk forge

I am able to upload the .rvt file to the bucket.
What I am looking for is to download the converted bubble in .zip format (using java SKD).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK itself, and the Forge API does not have an endpoint to do this. You need to parse the manifest, and download each item individually. An example written in Node.js is provided here: https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io, and the live demo here: https://extract.autodesk.io/. In future the endpoint might be added, but I do not know when it might be.

Comment: Is this the same reference I have to follow if i have to download the converted .svf file.

Comment: downloading the .svf file is not enough. the .svf file itself is a zip file which contains a manifest listing file references. You need to download all of them to get the 'bubble'.

Comment: need one clarification: I am successfully able to translate my .rvt file using "/modelderivative/v2/designdata".  and I verify the job complete using the urn returned by this.  When I try to get the derivatives from this manifest, it gives an empty list.  Where am I going wrong.

Comment: not sure I understand, if you see the manifest (with complete - success) them you see the derivatives, cannot be empty. You may need to share a bit of code and partial manifest json for us to understand.

Comment: The sample code I have take is is from forge-api-java-client samples, 
  
  refer method verifyJobComplete

     Response I get is  
     class ManifestDerivative {
      name: xxxx.rvt
      hasThumbnail: true
      outputType: svf
      progress: complete
      status: success
      children: [class ManifestChildren {
       }, ]
     class ManifestDerivative {
      name: null
      hasThumbnail: null
      outputType: thumbnail
      progress: complete
      status: success
      children: [class ManifestChildren {
  ...
     }
      }, ...]

Comment: :( can you share code and a sample file for investigation?

Comment: I will share the sample code, but if you can help me with the following question:  The steps I am following is  
  1. Authenticate  
 2. upload .rvt file    
 3. translate it to .svf with modelderivative/v2/designdata/job (response gives back a Job)   
 4. with the response check the job complete  
 5. I need to know whether the urn returned by this response is enough for downloading the bubble.  
Link to the response, after the file is translated  
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByrHSB-f7jP3TXhHYVQtOEUyM2c/view?usp=sharing  
 I don't see urn's for the derivatives